# How to add a HTML around a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have this array of strings :

```
array("Foo", "Foo RH 80", "Foo Foo RH 50 Foo", "Foo (RH 80 + 10) foo");
```

I'm looking for a way to add a tag like this :

```
array("Foo", "Foo <b>RH 80</b>", "Foo Foo <b>RH 50</b> Foo", "Foo <b>(RH 80 + 10)</b> foo");
```

I think I can do that with some REGEX, but it's too difficult to find the pattern.

Have you an idea ?

Comment: What pattern can be between `<b></b>`?

Comment: When string contains "RH XX" (XX is number) 
And when string contains "(RH XX + XX)" (Indeed, when RH is between ())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
/RH\s\d{2}|\(RH\s\d{2} \+ \d{2}\)/g
```

and replace with `<b>$0</b>`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/uC9oJ7/1)

Comment: Ok, it seems to be OK. But I have an other case :

"Foo (RH 80 et 20)". How to do with this "et" ?

Comment: It's ok with it :

RH\s\d{2}|\(RH\s\d{2} \+ \d{2}\)|\(RH\s\d{2} et \d{2}\) !

Really thanks for helping !!

Comment: @bahamut100 glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\(?\bRH \d+(?: \+ \d+)?\)?/', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using Regex:

If the beginning of your string is always the same, as it is in your example you could use simple string functions:

```
function boldify($pattern, $array){ 
    $new_array = array(); 
    foreach($array as $a) $new_array[] = $pattern."<b>".substr($a,strlen($pattern))."</b>";     
    return $new_array; 
}
```

[Here's a live example](http://3v4l.org/0LQJt)